# how can I solve this? keyword is not supported 'datasource'

Tags: c#, mysql, database

How can I fix this issue? Here is my code below:

```
"Datasource=localhost;port=3306;username=root; password=root";
```

How can I fix this code problem?

Answer (score 0):

Following the example [here](http://www.connectionstrings.com/mysql/), try this:

```
Server=localhost;Port=3306;Uid=root;Pwd=root;Database=myDataBase
```

You didn't supply a database, but it appears to be a requirement. Replace "myDataBase" above.

Answer (score 0):

Compare with this example:

```
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection conn;
string myConnectionString;

myConnectionString = "server=127.0.0.1;uid=root;" +
    "pwd=12345;database=test;";

try
{
    conn = new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection();
    conn.ConnectionString = myConnectionString;
    conn.Open();
}
catch (MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
```

And check your code.

Answer (score 0):

consider this example

```
Data Source=MyData.sdf;Persist Security Info=False;
```